# Error on running command "docker-compose ps"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new on docker and following a youtube tutorial video.
Could you pls advise on my error? Thanks in advance!
I got this error when running the "docker-compose ps" on the terminal:

```
Bong@Macbooks-MacBook-Pro mssql % docker-compose ps
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.sql-server-db: 'container-name'
Bong@Macbooks-MacBook-Pro mssql %
```

My code:

```
version: "3.7"
services: 
  sql-server-db: 
    container-name: sql-server-db
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "password"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

Comment: i think the docker-compose version is not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `container_name`, with an underscore